# Value Check in 4 cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following values from a table:

> 80, 90, 100, 110

We need a tab to be **shown only** in the following cases:

> 90, 100
>   80, 100
>   90, 80

And **not shown** in the following case:

> 80, 110

The code is below, but it doesn't show the tab, at **any** of the combinations.

```
for (l = 0; l <= $('table').length; l++) {
    tableId = $('table').attr('id');
    if (tableId != '') {
        // Here 4 is the column number of which the data I want.
        $('table tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
            var columnValue = parseInt($(this).find(':selected').val());
            console.log('COLUMN VALUE: ', columnValue);
            valueArray.push(columnValue);
        });
    }
}
console.log(valueArray);

var checkValue = false;
for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < checkArray.length; j++) {
        if (valueArray[i] == checkArray[j] > -1) {
            checkValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (takeattendancetab.length > 0) {
    var value = parseInt($('select[class*="menusubmissionid"]').val());

    console.log(checkValue);
    if (checkValue == true) {
        console.log('here');
        takeattendancetab.parent('a').removeClass('nolink');
        takeattendancetab.parent('a').attr('href',
            M.cfg.wwwroot + '/mod/facetoface/attendees.php?s=' +
            M.totara_f2f_attendees.config.sessionid +
            '&action=partreview'
        );
    } else {
        takeattendancetab.parent('a').addClass('nolink')
        takeattendancetab.parent('a').removeAttr('href');
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the logic behind? what happens with 110?

Comment: `80, 100` to be shown or not??? I guess you mean to not show `80, 110` but... EDIT: in fact i'm completly lost in getting any logic there

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong 100 instead of 110. If there is combination 80 and 110, then the tab should be not shown. In any other case, whe should see it.

Comment: @StartVader Can you share your HTML table or *tables* please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems you are fetching the values in the `valueArray` variable and then checking for the above conditions. Instead you can use below code,

```
if ($('table tr td:nth-child(4):contains(80)').length > 0 && $('table tr td:nth-child(4):contains(110)').length>0)
{  
    takeattendancetab.parent('a').addClass('nolink')
    takeattendancetab.parent('a').removeAttr("href");    

 } else {
    takeattendancetab.parent('a').removeClass('nolink');
    takeattendancetab.parent('a').attr("href", M.cfg.wwwroot + '/mod/facetoface/attendees.php?s=' + M.totara_f2f_attendees.config.sessionid + '&action=partreview');
}
```